MS Word Addin: how to retrieve characters / text prior to cursor location?
I am struggling with finding a way on how to retrieve the text prior to the current cursor location (no selection made). Anyone any idea?
Thanks a lot.
Expecting:
Do you want to create a solution that ex|tends the functionality of Word? --> "x"
Do you want to create a solution that |extends the functionality of Word? --> " "
|Do you want to create a solution that extends the functionality of Word? --> ""
Do you want to create a solution that extends the functionality of Word?| --> "?"
